# How can you combine Mathjax with Mathplayer?

Tags: mathjax

This site http://accessiblemath.dessci.com/2010/09/mathplayer-mathjax-more-accessible-math.html is telling me it's possible to combine Mathjax with Mathplayer to make mathematics display faster.

> A great feature of MathJax is that it can turn the display of math
>   over to a native MathML renderer such as MathPlayer. This results in
>   much faster display of the math.

Is this a good idea and if so, how should one go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. MathJax will recognize the presence of MathPlayer automatically and hand over rendering of any MathML. (MathJax will still convert TeX or AsciiMath to MathML first.)

Comment: So basicly `This results in much faster display of the math.` should be `This results in much faster display of math that is typeset in MathML`?

Comment: Depending on the configuration file you are using, the choice of whether to use MathML or HTML-CSS output will be made for you by MathJax, so that if IE with MathPlayer is used, you will get MathML output (sent to MathPlayer) and if you don't have MathPlayer installed, you will get HTML-CSS output.  So the effect is as described in the original quote.  If your configuration file end in `HTMLorMML`, then you will get this behavior.  (Of course if you use your own custom configuration, that may not be the case unless you include `MMLorHTML.js` in your `config` array.)

Comment: Also, note that MathJax *always* converts your math to MathML internally, even if you supply TeX or AsciiMath as the original form.  It is not clear from your message if you mean "typeset in MathML" to refer to the output from MathJax or the input from the author.  The input can be any of the three forms.  The output form can be selected by MathJax (as described above), or by the author (by using an explicit configuration).  The user can override the output form using the MathJax contextual menu to select a different renderer (so can always choose MathML output if that isn't the default).

Comment: I was referring to the input from the author.

Comment: Then, no, the original statement is correct.  The input format does not matter, as MathJax converts to MathML for output when IE/MathPlayer is used (and the appropriate configuration is included).  So the speed improvement would be for any of the input formats, not just math specified in MathML originally.